# Users can' t login at https store because of double frontend cookie

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie, https

I have a magento `version 1.9.2.4` installation with multiple store views with different urls. One new store view is now running with https in secure and unsecure base url. At this store many customers can't login, because there are two "frontend" cookies being set. One with the domain **.domain.de**, which is configured in the backend, and one with **.www.domain.de**. It's only that store with the ssl configuration, the other stores are running fine.

I read a lot of threads, but no one could help me out. My cookie configuration looks like the following:

**Default Session Cookie Management**

- Cookie Lifetime: 86400
- Cookie Path: /
- Cookie Domain:
- Use HTTP Only: Yes

**Default Session Validation Settings**

- Everything is set to "No"

**Store view Session Cookie Management**

- Cookie Domain: .domain.de

Are there any settings for stores running completely under https or is there anything else I can do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have ***n98-magerun.phar*** installed? Can you execute this `n98-magerun.phar config:get web/ ` and share it on the chat. Then change your actual domain to dummy domain so you can keep it anonymous.

Comment: No I don't have installed this

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the Dot (.) in the cookie domain. Please note that subdomains will no longer receive the cookies, however, Magento doesn't make usage of Subdomains by default (except you've changed that).

This has helped me to login again. If you cannot login into the backend, you can do that manually by moving to your database and set the flag in the `core_config_data` table

Comment: Hi Max, I added the dot because I need the cookie at my subdomains

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the subdomain for each of your store views. In case you have the following baseUrl setup:

- http://de.example.com
- http://en.example.com
- https://it.example.com

Your Cookie Domains should be exactly the same as so:

- de.example.com
- en.example.com
- it.example.com

Comment: The problem is, that i have to run the same store view under different domains. So i can't configure it like that

Comment: And the URLs have to be the same? Aren't redirects possible?

Comment: No, the urls are different, but I only have one store view to configure a cookie domain. So I can't set a cookie domain for each subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must have a same Cookie Domain and for share cookies between http and https you have to do a server configuration

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163828/reading-cookies-via-https-that-were-set-using-http

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on a few Magento sites with this issue. If any of the 'easy' configuration changes based fixes don't work, an alternate solution is to forcefully clear both frontend cookies on the login page.

The javascript to clear cookie by name 'frontend' would be easy enough something like this would work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593013/delete-cookie-by-name

Comment: Hmm, seems to be a solution, but I don't like it so much ;-)